# bootstrap editable - how to transfer dropdown value to SQL table?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I am currently working on a project that shows data from an SQL table using bootstrap editable for live editing.

It works fine - changes are transferred to the SQL table. What is already working?:

1. Showing current value from SQL table
2. Providing a drop-down for selection
3. Transferring changed values to SQL table

-> BUT Part 3 (transferring changed value) is only working for free-text input (class xedit).

**What I am looking for is the code for: transferring chosen value of drop-down-list to SQL-Table**

Here is the HTML-code:

```html
   <?php
    include("connect.php");
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css">
        <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">    
      <div style="text-align:center;width:100%;font-size:24px;margin-bottom:20px;color: #2875BB;">EDIT YOUR CHARACTERS</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <table class= "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 180px;" tabindex="0">NAME</th>
                                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 220px;" tabindex="0">ROLE</th>
                                    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="width: 288px;" tabindex="0">SECOND ROLE</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php
          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters");
          $i=0;
          while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
           if($i%2==0) $class = 'even'; else $class = 'odd';
           
           echo'<tr class="'.$class.'">

                                    <td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="name">'.$fetch['name'].'</td>
            <td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="role">'.$fetch['role'].'</td>
            <td class="xedit2" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="secondrole"><a href="#" class="rolestatus" data-type="select" data-pk="3" data-url="" data-title="Select status">'.$fetch['secondrole'].' </a></td>
                                    </td>
                     
                                </tr>'; 
                            }
          ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
            </div>
            </div>              
      <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
            
            
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.rolestatus').editable({    
            source: [
                  {value: 1, text: 'DD'},
                  {value: 2, text: 'HEAL'},
                  {value: 3, text: 'TANK'}
               ]
        }); 
    });
    </script>
            
            
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
            $('.xedit').editable();  
      $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
      var key = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('key');
    var x = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('id');
    var y = $('.input-sm').val();
    var z = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().text(y);

       $.ajax({
        url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+'&key='+key,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(s){
         if(s == 'status'){
         $(z).html(y);}
         if(s == 'error') {
         alert('Error Processing your Request!');}
        },
        error: function(e){
         alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
        }
       });
      });
    });
    </script>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the process.php code

```html
          <?php
          include("connect.php");
          if($_GET['id'] and $_GET['data'])
          {
       $id = $_GET['id'];
          $data = $_GET['data'];
          $key = $_GET['key'];
          if(mysql_query("update characters set $key='$data' where id='$id'"))
       echo 'success';
          }
          ?>
```

So does anybody know how I can transfer the chosen dropdown-value (class -> xedit2) to SQL table?

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exacly how x-editable works

But in first look i think that the type of your ajax should be "POST" if you want to update some data. And in my opinion you have syntax error in your sql query near "$key"